# indexOf for a list of tuples with implicit element

Tags: scala

unfortunately I receive as index -1, whereas I would have liked to receive index 2
Is there an alternative without going through my table for this problem?

```
val a = Array((1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(4,3));
a.indexOf(Tuple2[Int,Int](2,_))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "implicit element". The `Tuple2[Int, Int](2, _)` is a partially applied pair constructor. Your list does not contain any constructors, so you get a `-1`.

If you wanted to find the index of the first occurrence of a tuple that has `2` as first element, you could try something like this:

```
a.indexWhere(_._1 == 2)
```

or (if you don't remember that there is `indexWhere`, like me and Dima) :

```
a.view.zipWithIndex.find{ case ((2, _), idx) => true ; case _ => false }.map(_._2)
```

or

```
a.view.zipWithIndex.collect{ case ((2, _), idx) => idx }.headOption
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that doesn't work (I don't even understand how you manage to get -1 from that, it should not compile at all). `indexOf` is looking for the exact match on the array element, you can't give it wild cards.

Something like this would do what you want:

```
a.iterator
 .zipWithIndex
 .collectFirst { case ((2, _), idx) => idx }
 .getOrElse(-1)
```

Alternatively, use `indices`, but that only works for arrays:

```
a.indices.find(a(i)._1 == 2).getOrElse(-1)
```

Comment: That's because "use-case". The full Signature is: `indexOf[B >: A](elem: B): Int `, so it silently infers `Any` as LUB of `Int` and `Int => (Int, Int)`, and happily applies `indexOf` to the partially applied constructor. I agree, it's weird.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it didn't compile for me (in 2.11) ... Wanted `:Int` after `_`

Comment: 2.12.8 (current Scastie version) does accept it, and produces `-1`. But 2.12.5 didn't accept it, so 2.11 shouldn't accept it either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexWhere` to find an index of the element, that matches a function predicate, and `PartialFunction.cond` to convert your pattern to such a predicate:

```
scala> a.indexWhere(PartialFunction.cond(_) { case (2, _) => true })
res1: Int = 2
```